# issues using file with Xcode c

Tags: c, xcode

When I run this program with a file imported into Xcode, I receive an error of `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1 address=0x68)` at the line `c = fgetc(ptr);`. I am not sure why `fptr` is null when it gets to this line. Any help would be great thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define  M 100
#define N 100
char array[M][N] = {0};
void readFile();
void findStartandEnd();
void mazeTraversal();
int m = 0;
int n = 0;
int start[2] = {0};
int end[2] = {0};

int main() {
    readFile();
    //findStartandEnd();
    //mazeTraversal();
}

void readFile() {
    FILE *fptr;
    char c;
    char file_name[20];
    int i, j;

    printf("Please enter the size of the MxN maze.\n");
    printf("Start with the M size then the N size follow each number by the return key.\n");
    scanf("%d", &m);
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("Type in the name of the file containing the Field\n");
    scanf("%s", file_name);
    fptr = fopen(file_name, "r");
    for (i = 0; i < M && i < m; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < N && j < n; j++) {
            c = fgetc(fptr);
            while (!((c == '1') || (c =='0')))
                c = fgetc(fptr);
            array[i][j] = c;
        }
    fclose(fptr);

    for (i = 0; i < M && i < m; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < N && j < n; j++) {
            if (j == 0) printf("\n");
            printf("%c  ", array[i][j]);
        }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Have you checked to verify that `fptr` is valid?  You really ought to make sure that the file successfully opened before you dereference what might be a NULL pointer.

Comment: @ChadBrown: why did you roll back the edit?

Comment: `void readFile();` etc. are not valid prototypes and use a deprecated syntax.

Comment: Because you passed a null pointer to `fgetc`.

Answer (score 1):

You do not test if `scanf` correctly parsed a string into `file_name`.  You do not even protect `file_name` from a potential buffer overflow with `scanf("%19s", file_name);`

Furthermore, you do not test whether `fopen` succeeded at opening the file.  `fptr` could be `NULL` for many possible reasons, you must test that and fail gracefully.

Note that `scanf` will stop at the first white space character after the first word.  Filenames with embedded spaces cannot be entered with this method.

Note also that `c` should be defined as `int` instead of `char` to properly test for end of file as `EOF` returned by `fgetc()` does not fit in a `char`.

You should also use braces around non trivial statements commended by the `for` loops. They are not strictly necessary, but it will avoid silly bugs when later amending your code.